# How to return values after inner foreach loop in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In this `GetValidMapIndividuals` method I want to return `individualList` object. but here
it is not returning anything. If I moved this `return individualList;` near the `individualList.Add(viewModel);` this method is return only one from the list. so how can I fix this issue.

```
string profilePictureUrl;

        public List<MapIndividualsViewModel> GetValidMapIndividuals(ProjectRef projectRef)
        {
            var individualList = new List<MapIndividualsViewModel>();
            var eventsList = new List<Common.v2.DataModel.Events>();
            var filteredIndividuals = new List<Common.v2.DataModel.Individuals>();
            Preference preference = _preferenceServiceResolver.GetPreference(projectRef);

            var places = _placeService.GetPlaces(projectRef);

            var filteredPlaces = places.Select(p => new
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Lat = p.Lat,
                Lng = p.Lng
            }).ToArray();

            foreach (var place in filteredPlaces)
            {
                var events = _eventService.GetByPlace(projectRef, place.Id);

                foreach (var e in events)
                {
                    eventsList.Add(e); // add each event to the list
                }
            }

            // Filter the events by name and project only the required properties
            var filteredEvents = eventsList.Where(e => e.Name == "BIRTH" || e.Name == "DEATH")
                                           .Select(e => new
                                           {
                                               Name = e.Name,
                                               Date = e.Date,
                                               ReferenceId = e.ReferenceId
                                           }).ToList();

            foreach (var evt in filteredEvents)
            {
                var individual = _individualServicev2.Get(projectRef, evt.ReferenceId);
                dynamic links = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(individual.Links);
                int profilePictureId = links.ProfilePictureId;
                profilePictureUrl = _multimediaServicev2.GetPrimaryUrl(projectRef, profilePictureId);

                filteredIndividuals.Add(individual);

                // Set properties of MapIndividualsViewModel objects
                foreach (var ind in filteredIndividuals)
                {
                    var viewModel = new MapIndividualsViewModel
                    {
                        Id = ind.Id,
                        DisplayName = ind.FullName,
                        Gender = ind.Gender,
                        AliveStatus = ind.AliveStatus,
                        ProfileImageUrl = profilePictureUrl,
                        BirthDate = filteredEvents.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ReferenceId == ind.Id && e.Name == "BIRTH")?.Date,
                        DeathDate = filteredEvents.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ReferenceId == ind.Id && e.Name == "DEATH")?.Date,
                        Latitude = filteredPlaces.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == ind.Id)?.Lat ?? 0,
                        Longitude = filteredPlaces.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == ind.Id)?.Lng ?? 0,
                    };
                    individualList.Add(viewModel);
                }
            }
            return individualList;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are nested loops here for `filteredEvents` and `filteredIndividuals`. You can try moving the inner loop (`filteredIndividuals`) outside of the loop for `filteredEvents`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have moved filteredIndividuals outside of the loop for filteredEvents. after that only filteredEvents work and break point will not comes to the filteredIndividuals. therefore still it is not return anything.

Comment: To come back to your initial question, are you sure this is not returning anything or is it returning some duplicates? To me it looks like this code might be returning duplicates. Is it possible to share a simple version of your code which can reproduce this issue?